# This is a mongo 3.2.8, on centos7. Issue is how to run mongo as mongod user, not root

Tags: centos7, mongodb

I have been logging in as root , and running mongo as `sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /var/lib/mongo -f /etc/mongod.conf --fork`

I am trying to run mongod as the "mongod" user, so that it matches the automation agents of mongod cloud manager. Right now, mongo is running under "root". I stopped it, and tried `su mongod` and then restarted it. It is still running under "root" however.

How do I properly configure mongo so that it starts up with mongod? I know that the user mongod exists, since I have mongod cloud agents (backup,monitoring,and automation agents) running as "mongod" user when I do the command `ps aux | grep mongo`

When I find the user in /etc/passwd. it looks like this:

mongod:x:994:991:mongod:/var/lib/mongo:/bin/false

What does the "/bin/false" represent, and is it safe to change that to "/bin/bash" , will that allow me to start mongo as that user?

MORE INFO:
I just now found that the /var/lib/mongo/ folder has root user as the owner, so that may be the issue. I will try to change the owner to mongod, and then try starting mongo as a service instead of with the mongo program with cli args.

Comment: Exactly how are you running mongod?

Comment: I was logging in as root , and running `sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /var/lib/mongo -f /etc/mongod.conf --fork`

Comment: Why are you doing that, instead of a normal startup?

Comment: Thats just the way I was running it, it was taken from a book. I tried to run it normally, but got an error, Its most likely because the data dir is owned by root. I will try changing owner of db data files to mongod owner, and try starting normally

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @Michael Hampton , I ended doing a `chown -R mongod:mongod .` when in the `/var/lib/mongo/` directory. Then I started mongo with the `sudo service mongod start` command instead of the using `mongod` directly. It is now running under the correct user, mongod.